# Help for Windows Mobile Phone Application Update

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

hi
i wrote a script to copy  a CAB file via FTP from the distant server to the Mobile. This is all working fine and the size matches. 
Now my problem is when i am trying to install the file on the Mobile, 
i receive the message "the install was unsuccessful" and when i copy directly from the server to the Mobile this is working 
Can you help me with  this :-(

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the file size is the same, but what about contents?  Are the files identical?  How are you transferring the CAB to the device manually?  Over ActiveSync/WMDC?  BE aware that ActiveSync may modify a file during transfer - especially if the CAB is signed and the device doesn't require signed CABs.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966348/mobile-compact-framework-2-0-install-unsuccessful-from-win7-generated-from-vs2008/5966798#5966798) for some background/similar behavior.

Comment: i am using OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp to copy the file via FTP. 
Manually mean i copy the file from my server and i paste it to my computer then i copy the same file into the Mobile that is working fine. 
It is the file copy via OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp who is not working . i just want to make the update of my application directely from the distant server ..

Comment: Again, do a binary compare of the working and non-working CAB.

Comment: the size of the CAB file on the server is 1.07 MB (1,129,122 bytes)
and when i use OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp  to copy the file is 1.09 MB (1,150,368.00 bytes) 

it is bigger i don't know why and it is not working

thanks for your help